# How to escape '@' in curl command password field

Tags: password, curl, escape-characters

My username is `user1` and password is `mypass8@`

I wish to pass this username and password to curl command.

How do i escape the `@` in the password when passing it to curl command ?

```
curl -k -X POST https://user1:mypass8@@myshop.com/job/build
```

I get the error message:

> MESSAGE:Invalid password/token for user: user1

I also tried the following but all fail stating the password is not right as the `2` charecter and not considered in the password by the `curl` command.

```
curl -k -X POST https://'user1:mypass8@'@myshop.com/job/build
curl -k -X POST https://"user1:mypass8@"@myshop.com/job/build
curl -k -X POST https://user1:"mypass8@"@myshop.com/job/build
curl -k -X POST https://user1:'mypass8@'@myshop.com/job/build
```

Update: the login I m trying is for Jenkins admin console.

Can you please suggest ?

Comment: Did you already try using `--user username:password`?  This is used as an example at https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/remote-access-api/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue using a base64 conversion...

```
echo -n '[USERNAME]:[PASSWORD]' | base64
```

This will generate a token to pass to curl as a header in this way:

```
curl -H 'Authorization: Basic [add value obtained from the previous cmd]'
```

Comment: Is this also for logging into Jenkins, like the user in the question is trying to do?  If not, this seems to be a solution to some other problem.

Comment: If the server accepts the user/password login, it should also get the base64 basic authorization, as long as it complies with the w3 specs.


Have a look at the w3 doc [here](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/spec.html#AA) and wiki [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)

The main thing to consider is that this protocol is not secure, so use it always with SSL/TLS connections or in a secure not public network.


[Here](https://javabydeveloper.com/basic-http-authentication-using-curl/) is another article that explains the steps in a clear way.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers!

Answer (score 4):

URLs use [percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) aka URL encoding.

`@` sign is `%40` in this encoding.

```
% curl -k -X POST https://user1:mypass8%40@myshop.com/job/build
```

Or alternatively with `-u` / `--user` parameter:

```
% curl -u user1:mypass8@ -k -X POST https://myshop.com/job/build
```

[RFC 3986 section 3.2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986.html#section-3.2.1) states:

> The userinfo subcomponent may consist of a user name and, optionally,
> scheme-specific information about how to gain authorization to access
> the resource.  The user information, if present, is followed by a
> commercial at-sign ("`@`") that delimits it from the host.

```
  userinfo    = *( unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" )
```

> Use of the format "`user:password`" in the userinfo field is
> deprecated.  Applications should not render as clear text any data
> after the first colon (":") character found within a userinfo
> subcomponent unless the data after the colon is the empty string
> (indicating no password).  Applications may choose to ignore or
> reject such data when it is received as part of a reference and
> should reject the storage of such data in unencrypted form.  The
> passing of authentication information in clear text has proven to be
> a security risk in almost every case where it has been used.

> Applications that render a URI for the sake of user feedback, such as
> in graphical hypertext browsing, should render userinfo in a way that
> is distinguished from the rest of a URI, when feasible.  Such
> rendering will assist the user in cases where the userinfo has been
> misleadingly crafted to look like a trusted domain name
> (Section 7.6).

Tested with this tiny Go application:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func auth(fn http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        user, pass, _ := r.BasicAuth()
        if !check(user, pass) {
            http.Error(w, `Unauthorized.`, 401)
            return
        }
        fn(w, r)
    }
}

func check(user string, pass string) bool {
    if user == `user` && pass == `pass@` {
        return true
    }

    return false
}

func index(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    writer.Write([]byte(`hello, world!`))
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", auth(index))
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Run server:

```
% go run .
```

Test:

```
% curl -k -X POST http://user:pass%40@127.0.0.1:8080/ 
hello, world!

% curl -k -X POST http://user:pass@127.0.0.1:8080/ 
Unauthorized.

% curl --version
curl 7.72.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.72.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1g zlib/1.2.11 zstd/1.4.5 libidn2/2.3.0 libpsl/0.21.1 (+libidn2/2.3.0) libssh2/1.9.0 nghttp2/1.41.0
Release-Date: 2020-08-19
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-API HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB PSL SPNEGO SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets zstd
```

Comment: I have had to do exactly this with `@`s and `:`s in HTTP basic-auth passwords in the past.

Answer (score 1):

I have had success with URL-encoding the `@`s.  The problem is that when you say `http://myuser:myp@ssword@host.example.com/file`, it sees the username as `myuser`, the password as `myp`, and the host as `ssword@host.example.com` which is obviously wrong.

So if you do something like:

```
user="myuser"
pass="$( printf 'myp@ssword' | sed 's/@/%40/g' )"
curl "https://${user}:${pass}@host.example.com/file"
```

you should have better luck.

Comment: i tried your suggestion and i still get `Invalid password/token` error

Comment: @Ashar Is the service that you're trying to authenticate with expecting a plaintext password, or a password that has been base64 encoded (or encoded with some other encoding)?

Comment: The service is Jenkins admin console page to which I need to login using `curl`

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know what the website looks like (assuming myshop.com is just an example) I am not sure if this could help.
Have you tried "-F" instead of "-X POST"? In case you are filling out a form that should work. That way you could put your password inside a file and call that files content with "<" like so:

```
curl -F password=</home/user/pw-file -F user=user1 myshop.com/job/build
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I need `-X POST` as a requirement here :(

Answer (score 0):

Not working:

```
curl -u user1:mypass8@ -k -X POST https://myshop.com/job/build
```

Working:

```
curl -u 'user1:mypass8@' -k -X POST https://myshop.com/job/build
```

The **single quote** '' is required if you have @ in your password

Comment: In what shell is `@` special in this way?